# Como criar um link para executar um arquivo ".bat" que fica dentro do diretorio PHP?

Tags: php, link

Galera, boa tarde!

Seguinte, eu tenho uma página em PHP que fica aberta monitorando um link, eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para colocar um link que abra um arquivo .bat que fica no mesmo diretorio da página...

Exemplo:

"Loja 1 Down - Click aqui" <-- Ao clicar nesse link ele abriria uma BAT que roda no servidor.

Eu não quero fazer isso com o PHP em sí, apenas chamar a BAT pelo Windows mesmo.

:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se preferir da pra chamar via Javascript:

`<input type="button" value="Click aqui" onclick="window.open('file:///C:pasta/teste.bat')" />`

Comment: esse metodo executaria um arquivo na maquina do usuário, e na pergunta ele quer que rode no servidor.

Comment: é infelizmente até agora não consegui! Isso que você postou faz o download do arquivo, e na verdade eu queria abri-lo! E o que complica ainda mais é o Google Chrome :/

Se alguem tiver sugestões!!!

Answer (score -1):

Tenta algo assim:

`system("cmd /c C:[caminho para o arquivo]");`

A função [System](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.system.php) serve para rodar comando no servidor da aplicação.

Comment: é infelizmente até agora não consegui! Isso que você postou faz o download do arquivo, e na verdade eu queria abri-lo! E o que complica ainda mais é o Google Chrome :/

Se alguem tiver sugestões!!!

Comment: acho que então voce misturou as coisas, da uma olhadinha na função system, ela nao faz download, ela executa algo no servidor